# React Apexchart Timeline Chart Unusable with Large Amounts of Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I'm looking to use React Apexchart's Timeline Chart to make a beautiful Gantt chart. However, the data I'm graphing could have several "Tasks" (y-axis labels) and each y-axis label could have dozens of "Action Items" associated with it. These Action items could be overlapping one another and need to be displayed stacked vertically.

React-Apexchart does a fantastic job with small data sets. However, now that I am receiving mass amounts of data it becomes unbearable trying to mouse hover over these bars to read the tooltips. Any ideas?

[image]

Ideally I would like it to be as readable and beautiful as it looks here. Even if the user must scroll vertically and horizontally.

Thanks everyone!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar.
How much space you want to allocate to each row/column is up to you. But his enables you to have scrolling on the chart.

```
const getHeight = () => {
    if (series[0]) {
      if (series[0].data.length < 30) {
        return undefined;
      } else {
        return series[0].data.length * 20.618;
      }
    }
    return undefined;
  };
  return (
    <Box sx={{ maxHeight: '50vh', display: 'block', overflow: loading ? '' : 'auto' }}>
      <ApexChart
        width={'98%'}
        loading={loading}
        height={getHeight()}
        options={options || {}}
        type={'bar'}
        data={series}
      />
    </Box>
  );
```